# Insert query in laravel 5.1 using foeach loop

Tags: arrays, foreach, insert, laravel-5.1

My code is:

```
  $store_ids=Input::get('store_inventory_ids');
        $store_product_inven_qty=Input::get('store_pro_inv_qty');
        $store_attri_ids=Input::get('store_attri_ids');
        $store_id_with_attri_id=Input::get('store_id_attri_id');

    foreach ($store_ids as $key => $store_id) { 
    ProStoreInventoryModel::insert([
    'product_id'=>'1',
    'store_id'=>$store_id,
    'attri_ids'=>'1',
    'attri_ids_with_store_id'=>'1',
    'product_qty'=>'1',
    'status'=>'1',
    'deletestatus'=>'0',
    'created_at'=>date('Y:m:d H:i:s'),
    'updated_at'=>date('Y:m:d H:i:s')
    ]);
    }
```

This is my model name: ProStoreInventoryModel

The below four variable haves 16 datas in array format.,

```
$store_ids, $store_product_inven_qty, $store_attri_ids, 
$store_id_with_attri_id.
```

I just looped main foreach, in that I wrote insert query, now how can I insert the remaining values?

Comment: what do you mean by remaining value ?

Comment: These three value., $store_product_inven_qty, $store_attri_ids, 
$store_id_with_attri_id

Comment: The all four variable contain some set of values in array format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use for loop for this, eg: you have 16 inputs, do this

```
$store_ids=Input::get('store_inventory_ids');
$store_product_inven_qty=Input::get('store_pro_inv_qty');
$store_attri_ids=Input::get('store_attri_ids');
$store_id_with_attri_id=Input::get('store_id_attri_id');



for($i=0; $i<count($store_ids); $i++){

ProStoreInventoryModel::insert([
    'product_id'=>'1',
    'store_id'=>$store_id[$i],
    'attri_ids'=>$store_attri_ids[$i],
    'attri_ids_with_store_id'=>$store_id_with_attri_id[$i],
    'product_qty'=>$store_product_inven_qty[$i],
    'status'=>'1',
    'deletestatus'=>'0',
    'created_at'=>date('Y:m:d H:i:s'),
    'updated_at'=>date('Y:m:d H:i:s')
]);

}
```

**OR do this**

```
for($i=0; $i<count($store_ids); $++){

    $data[] = 
    [
        'product_id'=>'1',
        'store_id'=>$store_id[$i],
        'attri_ids'=>$store_attri_ids[$i],
        'attri_ids_with_store_id'=>$store_id_with_attri_id[$i],
        'product_qty'=>$store_product_inven_qty[$i],
        'status'=>'1',
        'deletestatus'=>'0',
        'created_at'=>date('Y:m:d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at'=>date('Y:m:d H:i:s')
    ];


}

ProStoreInventoryModel::insert($data);
```

Comment: I just take the general loop and counted your input size, and grabbing one by one input values

Comment: which section you didn't understand ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107749/discussion-between-karnagowtham-and-qazi).